# Sagem MF-5482n printer on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, 9.10

I got a multifunctional printer Sagem MF-5482n. On their site there is a [Linux software for it](http://support.sagemcom.com/support-val/site/uk/faxes-printers-and-multifunctional-1/mf5462-mf5482n-698/driver) but for Ubuntu 9.10 but I am running Ubuntu 14.10 x64.

How can I install it?

Is the only way to install it to use windows ppd from windows drivers, or can I be able to do it with linux dedicated software?

Comment: Can you download the zip file in your Ubuntu machine and extract the contents in a folder? Then you can **edit the original question above** with details of that folder and the instructions inside the zip file if any.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Printers and scanners can perform their basic functions in Ubuntu without additional drivers. You can Install basic printer drivers and scanner drivers and see weather it works.

Scanner drivers:

```
Sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev
```

Printer Drivers :

```
sudo apt-get install cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-ppdc cups-server-common debconf ghostscript libavahi-client3 libavahi-common3 libc-bin libc6 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgcc1 libstdc++6 libusb-1.0-0 lsb-base poppler-utils procps
```